# How Can I Open the Modal Dialog Box in Checkout Authentication?

Tags: magento2, admin, backend, modal, open-graph

I want to make it so that when any User buys a product, when checkout is clicked on then the first modal dialog box opens to either login or use a guest account to purchase the product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Checkout the Code below or in the attached link
Link:
[magento/magento2/blob/487f5f45/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/sidebar.js#L52-L66](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/193899/how-can-open-modal-dialog-box-in-checkout-authentication)

Code:
events['click ' + this.options.button.checkout] = $.proxy(function () {
    var cart = customerData.get('cart'),
        customer = customerData.get('customer');

```
if (!customer().firstname && cart().isGuestCheckoutAllowed) {
    if (this.options.url.isRedirectRequired) {
        location.href = this.options.url.loginUrl;
    } else {
        authenticationPopup.showModal();
    }

    return false;
}
location.href = this.options.url.checkout;
}, this);
```